# Lightning and browser back/forward navigation not reloading page

Tags: lightning, lightning-events, navigation, browser, caching

When going back in the browser from one lightning page to another, I have a situation where data that was modified in a subsequent page is now stale on the previous one and the user has to refresh to get the updated data.

The init event isn't fired, so instead I tried to use `aura:locationChange` and in that use `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()`, but that doesn't seem to work.

And even if it did, it feels like a hacky way of doing it - locationChange fires multiple times on a single browser back.

Is there a consistent way to get a browser navigation event? So the controller then can decide whether we need to do a refresh or not?

Comment: I suppose I could poll a flag set on the service that is changed when the subsequent page is, but again that feels pretty nasty.